# How to achieve such an awesome colors and skin tones in Lightroom and/or Photoshop?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

Anybody willing to explain how to achieve this look in Lightroom and/or Photoshop?

I'm mostly using Lightroom, so I tried crushing the blacks, increasing the contrast and vibrance, increasing R and G in the midtones, lowering the B in the midtones... Also played with split toning and HSL but everytime something's missing or overdone.

I'm lost, please help me! :)

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it.

Comment: I am almost sure, that this images were not only post processed, but the were made in very good lighting condition not even saying about studio lighting. Especially the last shot is definitely well lightened at front. But having this I am always using vibrance and blacks. Or you may buy or download some presets for portraits.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. (I can't read your mind.) Can you post at least one example of what you have tried? And state explicitly how it differs from what you are trying to achieve. (Just to be clear - if you talk about "this look", I don't know what you are referring to.)

Comment: @Seweryn Habdank-Wojewódzki I'm not so sure about the studio lighting. I would say good natural light (most are outdoors), probably golden hour, and exposed for the subject - you see how the highlights are blown. Even the last one has blown highlights. It won't be the case if it's well lit. And good postprocessing skills. But I'm not sure, that's why I need help.

Comment: @osullic I tried to add one of my tries to the original post but it says "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 8 links." Should I add an answer to the question to show what I achieved today trying to reproduce this look, so you could see and help me? And by "this look" I mean, as stated in the title, the colors - bright, vivid, warm, and also the skin tones.

Comment: Remove a couple of the less-important/relevant 3rd party images. [It would also be nice if you credited their copyright owners]

Comment: @Emma could you please  post your photo to see what is to be done?

Comment: My last try https://bit.ly/2yqA20Q

Comment: Osullic and Seweryn Habdank-Wojewódzki, anything? You so insisted to see my photo that I thought you wanted to help. And now nothing. Please tell me what do you think - what I could change to approach the colors and skin tones in the showed images? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Looking closely at the images, the first thing I notice are the following points;

1. The images seem staged as in stock photography.
2. Beside the first image which is lit from the side, the rest seem to be backlit.
3. The natural light coming through is very soft; perhaps a cloudy overcast day.
4. All images seem exposed for the shadows which is what seems to be producing the low contrast soft look with the blow-out highlights.
5. The subjects also seem to be exposed with reflected light, maybe a reflector or a wall

All the above will definitely produce the results you have attached straight from the camera and I believe that’s what has taken place with regards to these images.

However, if you wanted to attempt to achieve something similar in Lightroom, you can try something as follows;

1. Contrast – Slide to the Left – create softness
2. Dehaze – Slide to the Right – Increase definition
3. Highlights – Slide to the Right – Blowout the Highlights
4. Shadows – Slide to the Right – Create further softness whilst increase exposure in the subjects
5. Black – Slide to the Left – again, will add to the overall softness
6. White – Slide to the Right – increase ambient white
7. Saturation – Yellow Decrease // Orange Increase – To me, there seems to be low levels of Yellow in the subjects and a slight increase in Orange.

Please note, these adjustments will work better to enhance any image that is already close to what you wish the end product to look like. 
If you have an image that is front-lit with a dark background, you will find it very difficult to create a natural looking back-lit effect.

Comment: Thank you for your kind guidance. I should probably more think about getting the image in-camera than in pp.